# optional parameter in Laravel routes always return 404 page if parameter is not provided

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am working on an application and I don't understand whats going on here.

In my routes, I have added an optional parameter but it returns 404 pages in case if I don't provide the optional parameter. The routes should be working on both instances with or without optional parameters.

and Another thing is that I also want to add where condition on route parameter but it doesn't work.

web.php

```
Route::get('invoices/{type?}/create', 'InvoiceController@create')->where('type', '[A-Za-z]+')->name('invoices.create');
Route::post('invoices/{type?}', 'InvoiceController@store')->where('type', '[A-Za-z]+')->name('invoices.store');

Route::resource('invoices', 'InvoiceController')->except([
    'create', 'store' 
]);
```

InvoiceController.php

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create(Request $request, $type = null)
{
    echo $type;
    die;
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request, InvoiceValidator $invoiceValidator, $type = null)
{
    echo $type;
    die;
}
```

When I enter the URL "http://localhost/project/invoices/create" it returns 404 and when I enter "http://localhost/project/invoices/recurring/create" then It echos "recurring" value in the controller.

I have even tried by removing the where clause on the routes but still not working. and also try by clearing the routes cache and reordering of the routes. But still have the same issue.

web.php(Even the following not working)

```
Route::get('invoices/{type?}/create', 'InvoiceController@create')->name('invoices.create');
Route::post('invoices/{type?}', 'InvoiceController@store')->name('invoices.store');

Route::resource('invoices', 'InvoiceController')->except([
    'create', 'store' 
]);
```

Comment: Check `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Yes @catcon, But I am totally surprised by this behaviour of the Laravel. So we can't use optional parameter in the middle. Right?

Answer (score 3):

You need to avoid ambiguity by moving the optional parameter to the end of the route